# Square root and def function?

Tags: python, square-root

As I've progressed a little more in Python I thought I would try out the define function. I've made this simple square root calculator. Please explain as simple as you can?

```
import math

def mathprob(x):
    math.sqrt(x)

yn = input()
num = int(input("Enter number to be square rooted."))

if yn == 'sqrt':
    ans = mathprob(num)
    print(ans)

elif yn == '':
    print("bye! :(")
    quit()
```

Comment: explain what?  What is your question exactly?

Comment: Haha sorry. But when I type in the number to be square rooted,  the program just stops

Comment: Are you sure that you're typing `'sqrt'` before you enter the number?  If you're doing that, you should at least see `None` printed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to **return** the value from your function, otherwise it returns `None`:

```
def mathprob(x):
     return math.sqrt(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually return something from your function, you can do it like this:

```
def mathprob(x):
    return math.sqrt(x)
```

Comment: The OP is probably using Python 3, given the use of print(), therefore raw_input is not required.

Comment: Oh, has that changed in Python 3? I didn't know that.